# Android: Error converting type Date to Calendar

Tags: android

I am using realm to save a date but need to use the day and month of the date for later use so am converting the type Date to Calendar using:

```
 public static Calendar toCalendar(Date date){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    return cal;
}
```

Then on onCreate of a fragment:

```
Date testDate = new Date();
CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("MMMM d, yyyy ", testDate.getTime());
Log.d("Date", String.valueOf(s));
// This prints May 26, 2017 

Calendar testCalendar = toCalendar(testDate);
Log.d("CALENDAR DAY TEST", String.valueOf(testCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
// This prints 5, MONTH prints 2. Rather the expected 26 & 5.
```

The DAY_OF_MONTH and MONTH methods of testCalendar are returning the day as the 5th and month as the 2nd rather than the 26th and 5th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are static ints used for tellling Calendar what type of data you want.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```